# Как отправить кастомные куки jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Необходимо составить map с cookie которые будут вписаны туда как string, что бы потом отправить их с помощью jsoup.cookies()
Как сделать это правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");
map.put("key3", "value3");
//собственно сама строка - key1=value1, key2=value2, key3=value3
String out = map.toString().replace("{","").replace("}","");
//здесь в jsoup вставляем нашу строку в куки
//можно в header
Jsoup.connect(url).header("Set-Cookie:", out).ignoreContentType(true).get();
//или
Jsoup.connect(url).header("Cookie:", out.replase(",",";")+";").ignoreContentType(true).get();
//либо как куки
Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(map).ignoreContentType(true).get();
```